# Moodle exam with minimum zero points for multiple choice task

Tags: r, r-exams

How can I create a moodle question via the `{exams}` package that scores multiple choice questions with at least zero points?

I already tried:

```
exams2moodle(..., mchoice = list(eval = list(negative = FALSE)))
```

Comment: The default should be that multiple-choice exercises have partial credits with a non-negative point sum. Could you elaborate which behavior you want and what you currently get? Then I'll take a closer look when I'm sitting at a proper computer again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then the default setting in `exams_eval()` and hence also in `exams2moodle()` does what you look for:

- `partial = TRUE`, i.e., there are partial credits for each correct list item that is checked.
- `rule = "false2"`, i.e., there are negative partial credicts for each incorrect list item that is checked.
- `negative = FALSE`, i.e., the sum of points within the exercise cannot become negative.

As an illustration I generated `exams2moodle("switzerland", points = 5)` which generates an exercise where the first two list items are correct (yielding 5/2 positive points each) and the other three list items are incorrect (yielding 5/3 negative points each).

With 1 correct and 1 incorrect item you get 0.83 points = 5/2 - 5/3.

[image: moodle 1]

The point some of 1 correct and 2 incorrect items would be -0.83 points = 5/2 - 2 * 5/3; but it is constrained to be zero:

[image: moodle 2]

And a last variation to show how this works: 2 correct and 2 incorrect yielding 1.67 points = 2 * 5/2 - 2 * 5/3.

[image: moodle 3]